# How well does Microsoft Office Excel work in Wine?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

Some interest in Excel 2003, but primarily in Excel 2007. Wondering if advanced features, such as macros can be made to work flawlessly. Or if there are any major issues I should know about.

Using an alternative open source native program is unfortunately out of the question due to complex macro/VBA heavy spreadsheets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Excel 2007](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12812) should work well with some adjustments.

[Excel 2003](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2736) is unlikely to work properly.

Always look on the [wine application database](http://appdb.winehq.org/) to find out how well a program can be run in wine.

Comment: Why should the 2003 version be less compatible? I always had the impression that older windows software is more likely to work with wine... appdb says platinum on 2003 and only bronze on 2007.

Answer (score 2):

MS Office 2007 works well in Ubuntu 12.10, with following inconveniences:
- when any *office app is started, another launcher opens in Unity bar with default WINE icon... :( (I have managed to get proper launchers through Drag/drop from Dashboard, however after the Launcher is clicked it opens under new launcher with WINE icon.)

After some upgrade I can't associate extensions to MS Office apps. as well, apart from that it is working fairly good.

I haven't tested macros abilities, as they are not-essential in my work environment, hence not used.

Answer (score 1):

if you use playonlinux then both will work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Just installed latest PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 11.10 desktop, Macros did not work at all under Excel 2007. Everytime I try to run the macro, even the simplest one-liners, it crashes.