# How can I get Microsoft Excel 2003 to work in Wine?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I used to be a MS Excel 2003 guru. I installed MS Office in Ubuntu with Wine, but the Macros make Excel crash.

Is there any way to get this working? I've been thinking to install VMWare with WinXP, but I would like to run Excel (for instance) from the Ubuntu desktop (I don't know if that's possible).

I've tried to install the dll's in Wine, but without success.

Whining: I've tried to 'work' with OpenOffice, but the language and the IDE are getting to me. I'm trying to create a database with base and extract the data with calc, but I've been struggling for days where I would have finished already with Access/Excel.

**Edit:** Finally with VMWare Player, WinXP & Office 2003, I'm set to go...

Comment: Just saw this http://askubuntu.com/questions/1686/how-well-does-microsoft-office-excel-work-in-wine. Seems like Excel 2003 doesn't work with wine.

Comment: yep, VMWare with XP or Remote Desktop should be your friends. For documents you could give LyX a chance, though ;)

Comment: I'll give Crossover a try http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/group/?app_id=779

Comment: @type Thanks, I've no problem with Writer for documents. I'm not trying to do anything advanced there.

Comment: @GUI Junkie : Does Excel 2007 crash when using Macros also ?

Comment: @Binarylife, I don't own a legal copy of Excel 2003, so I can't say. But if you look at the linked question, it seems like Excel 2007 does work correctly.

Comment: @GUI Junkie : I see , I'd recommend to give [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) a try .  see how to [install](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-install-libreoffice-34-in-ubuntu.html) LibreOffice latest version . It has many new features and improvements and more integration in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Binarylife thanks, I'll give that a try. I do have a legal copy of 2003, but not of 2007.

Comment: OP requested this question to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

While you try to get used to **LibreOffice** (OpenOffice.org is essentially dead, so you should switch), you can try to install MS Office Excel with PlayOnLinux. It is available in the repositories, and makes installing most common/important Windows applications a breeze.

Comment: Pd. I don't know if OpenOffice is dead, but it should be taken out to the back and be shot

Comment: So what's the difference between OpenOffice and LibreOffice apart from the serial number?

Comment: Ah, I've tried PlayOnLinux, but it leans on Wine so the result is that I've uninstalled Office. I'll try again when I can.